# Cell-phone golf

Tags: code-challenge

Older cellphones have 3 or 4 characters mapped to each number from 2-9 and that number must be pressed a certain number of times to get the required character. Let's assume our cellphone has this map:

```
1:1
2:abcABC2
3:defDEF3
4:ghiGHI4
5:jklJKL5
6:mnoMNO6
7:pqrsPQRS7
8:tuvTUV8
9:wxyzWXYZ9
0:<space><newline>0
```

If you want to type `b`, it will take 2 presses of the `2` key since `b` is mapped to the second position on the `2` key.

To type `exaMPle TExt 01` , you would press `33 99 2 6666 77777 555 33 0 8888 33333 99 8 0 <a 1-sec pause here in real life but we'll ignore it>000 1`

Additionally, the `*` key brings up the following page of special characters:

```
.,'?!
"-()@
/:_;+
&%*=<
>£€$¥
¤[]{}
\~^¡¿
§#|`
```

The first character `.` is highlighted. You can navigate to each character in four directions. It takes one additional key press to insert. So to insert `$`, you would press `*↓↓↓↓→→→<select>` i.e. a total of 9 key-presses.

---

Your program must take input (STDIN or prompt) of contact names followed by a newline followed by whatever numbers a person types on that phone's keyboard.

Eg.

```
JOHN DOE
JANE DOE
BOBBY TABLES

36
```

Your program must output the list of contacts which match `any` of the characters mapped to the keys the user presses.
In this example, since the user pressed `36`, the output list must consist of all contacts that match (completely or partially) the regex `\b[d-fD-F3][m-oM-O6]` since:

```
   3       6
   |       |
   v       v
[d-fD-F3][m-oM-O6]
```

In this case, the output would be:

```
JOHN DOE
JANE DOE
```

All contacts should be considered case insensitive. So `36` should match `jOhN Doe`, `JAne doE` , etc...

If no contacts match, you should output a blank line.

**Details**:

- Input "contacts" will be `^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$`. Numbers are allowed.
- Input numbers will be `[0-9]+` (obviously)
- Your source code may contain any characters from `[0-9a-zA-Z \n]` UNION `<chars from special chars table>`

---

### Scoring

Your score will be the number of key-presses that it takes to type out your program on this particular phone. Lowest score wins.

You can use programs in [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/32817/calculate-cell-phone-keypresses) for scoring.

---

<sup>Here's the original sandbox question - http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1790/8766</sup>

Comment: Very similar to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/42220/31414

Comment: Do we have to parse the Unicode characters like `→`?

Comment: @KSFT NO, the arrows are only placeholders to indicate keypresses. You need to parse only the characters in the keymaps.

Comment: @user80551 I'm confused. Are we supposed to parse characters or keypresses?

Comment: @KSFT You are supposed to parse words followed by characters within [0-9]. Your program will be scored based on number of "keypresses" required to type its source.

Comment: Ah...So, the names will never contain characters other than letters and spaces?

Comment: @KSFT And numbers. `JOHN DOE 2` is valid input.

Comment: Shouldn't the example regex be /[d-fD-F3][m-oM-O6]/, then?

Comment: @KSFT You're right; detailed it in the question

Comment: I know the "boby tables" reference. ;-)

Comment: @proudhaskeller almost all people here do